# Item labels are outside document page margin with lualatex?

Tags: xetex, luatex, lists, babel, polyglossia

I am using Latex for my homework assignments in our native language Hebrew. I've been using `polyglossia` with `XeLateX` until now, but after encountering several annoying bugs I couldn't figure out how to solve, I decided to switch to `babel` + `LuaLateX` (Plus, I find the API of `babel` nicer than `polyglossia`).

I tried to compile one of the assignments I had, and after several tweaking I got it to look like it used to be with the previous setup except for one problem I didn't manage to solve. Whenever I use a list environment such as `itemize`, `enumerate`, or `description`, the labels for the items (bullets/index/notes) appear outside the page margin which doesn't look good in my opinion:
[image]

It's even worse in a `description` environment as the item's note clips outside the page entirely.

Compare this to the same document compiled with my old setup of `XeLateX` + `polyglossia`:
[image]

As you can see, nothing is outside the page margins, and the items are even indented with `itemize` (I intentionally disabled indentation in the `enumerate` environment in the middle. I think it looks better).

For the `itemize` environment I just use `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` without anything special at all. For `description` I use something like:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[הערה]
ספין הוא תנע זוויתי המשויך לחלקיק ומקנה לו מומנט מגנטי אינטרינזי. הוא אינו נובע מתנועה סיבובית, וגם לחלקיקים שאינם טעונים חשמלית (כמו נויטרונים) יש ספין. הספין יכול להימדד בערכים בדידים
בלבד כאשר סט הערכים האפשריים תלוי בסוג החלקיק. מבחינה מיקרוסקופית, לספין אין אנלוג במכניקה הקלאסית, אך במקרים רבים ניתן לנתח מערכות של ספינים באמצעות מכניקה סטטיסטית קלאסית.
\end{description}
```

which is a standard use of the `description` environment. For the `enumerate`, I actually use a custom list with these settings:

```
\newlist{QuestionParts}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[QuestionParts, 1]{align=left, leftmargin=*, label=\alph*.}
\setlist[QuestionParts, 2]{align=right, label=\arabic*.}
```

It shouldn't have anything that causes it to go outside the margin.

I think it's safe to assume that `babel` doesn't change how lists indentation works so I am almost sure the culprit is `LuaLatex`. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix this to get a result similar to my old document?

I don't think it's related to the issue but just to make sure, here's the code that sets up `babel` in my new setup (this code is in a custom package I use for all my styling and settings):

```
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\newboolean{hebrew}
\setboolean{hebrew}{false}

\DeclareOption{hebrew}{\setboolean{hebrew}{true}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{my-style}{Unknown '\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{mathpazo}
\RequirePackage[bidi=basic, provide=*]{babel}

\babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{hebrew}}
}{
    \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\selectlanguage{english}}
}
```

and here's the `polyglossia` code from my old setup:

```
\newboolean{hebrew}
\setboolean{hebrew}{false}

\DeclareOption{hebrew}{\setboolean{hebrew}{true}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{my-style}{Unknown '\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Font and language settings
\RequirePackage{mathpazo}

\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
    Script=Hebrew,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
]{Assistant}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{hebrew}}{
    \setmainlanguage{hebrew}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \setsansfont{Assistant}
}{
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
}
```

Other than these pieces of code that set up the language of the document, which I don't believe are responsible for this problem, the two documents are exactly the same.

Comment: Without a MWE it’s difficult to say, but I think the problem is you are not declaring `hebrew` as the main language. There are a couple of full examples in Hebrew in https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/main/samples .

Comment: Declaring `hebrew` as the main language indeed solved the problem. Thank you. If you turn this comment into an answer, I could accept it.